# Android webView doesn´t show Geo location

Tags: java, android

So we made a html5 webapp which uses geo Data.

When I open it on my local chrome browser it shows all locations and my current location.

If I open it on the app it shows all locations but not mine... how could I fix that?

**Here is the code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /**
     * WebViewClient subclass loads all hyperlinks in the existing WebView
     */
    public class GeoWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // When user clicks a hyperlink, load in the existing WebView
            if(url.startsWith("geo:"))
            {
                Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse(url);
                Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
                mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivity(mapIntent);
                }
                return true;
            }
            view.loadUrl(url);

            return true;
        }




    }

    public class GeoWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        @Override
        public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin,
                                                       GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
            // Always grant permission since the app itself requires location
            // permission and the user has therefore already granted it
            callback.invoke(origin, false, false);
        }


    }

    WebView mWebView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        // Brower niceties -- pinch / zoom, follow links in place
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new GeoWebViewClient());
        // Below required for geolocation
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new GeoWebChromeClient());

        mWebView.loadUrl("http://insert-website-here.de");

    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // Pop the browser back stack or exit the activity
        if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        }
        else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

**I thought that this will fix it:**

```
public class GeoWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    @Override
    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin,
                                                   GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
        // Always grant permission since the app itself requires location
        // permission and the user has therefore already granted it
        callback.invoke(origin, false, false);
    }


}
```

but it doesnt look like..any ideas?

**Here are my permissions:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: what is your api level in manifesto ??

Comment: you have need to extends Activity with Fragment and google support api you should use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript must be enabled in the WebView, using `WebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`
The `WebView` must use a custom `WebChromeClient` which implements `WebChromeClient.onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt().`

This method is called by the `WebView` to obtain permission to disclose the user's location to JavaScript. (In the case of the browser, we show a prompt to the user.) The default implementation does nothing, so permission is never obtained and the location is never passed to JavaScript. A simple implementation which always grants permission is ...

```
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
 public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
    callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
 }
});
```

The location of the database is set using `WebSettings.setGeolocationDatabasePath(...)`

```
webView.getSettings().setGeolocationDatabasePath( context.getFilesDir().getPath() );
```